# Typo in Markdown help

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting, editing-help

On the [editing help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting), there's an example showing syntax highlighting with a specified language.

For C# it specifies `<!-- language: c# -->` (you need to expand the section to see it), however this doesn't actually work.

It should be `<!-- language: csharp -->`.

Comment: I believe this is correct, "You can use either one of the supported prettify language codes, like lang-cpp or lang-sql, **or you can specify a tag**, "

Comment: I can use this correctly on the main site. It won't work here on meta because meta doesn't have a c# tag.

Comment: I tried using "c#" on http://stackoverflow.com/a/28865671/270348 and it didn't work.

Comment: @RobSiklos It's not in the revision history.

Comment: @Servy that's because I made the edit too soon after posting the answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`csharp` is a Google Prettifier language code, so you'd spell it like:

```
<!-- language: lang-csharp -->
```

or

```
<!-- language: lang-cs -->
```

Note the `lang-` prefix. Without the prefix you can specify a Stack Exchange tag name, and then you'd use `c#`, so there is *no bug* here. The [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) tag is configured to use `lang-cs` already, see the [bottom of the tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info#prev-value):

> Code Language (used for [syntax highlighting](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html)): lang-cs

As it happens, `csharp` is also a tag; it is a synonym for the `[tag:c#]` tag, so the same language association is in effect.

You may have missed this on the editing help page, but it is clearly documented there:

> You can use either [one of the supported prettify language codes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify/81970#81970), like `lang-cpp` or `lang-sql`, or you can specify a tag, and the syntax highlighting language associated with this tag will be used.

I changed [your answer source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25532160/microsoft-team-foundation-server-express-2012-how-to-clean-up-in-tbl-testresul/28865671#28865671) to use `<!-- language: c# -->` and the highlighting is working just fine still. Perhaps you tried this in the editing preview and didn't wait for the timeout to pass before highlighting is applied?

Comment: Very weird, I don't understand why it seems to be working now. Oh well, sorry for the spam, I guess.

Comment: @RobSiklos it could be you forgot the newline before the comment or made another typo along those lines.

Comment: Syntax highlighting doesn't always work in the editing preview.

Comment: @NisseEngström did you wait a few seconds? Highlighting is only applied after you *stop* editing for a while, after a timeout.

Comment: @MartinPieters: Much more than five seconds. I have no idea why it doesn't work occasionally.

Comment: @NisseEngström I never use tags in the syntax, I always use the `lang-` prefix. Perhaps that is the difference? Using a tag requires looking up the right Prettifier language to use on the server.